# Is selenium IDE an XUL add-on in Firefox?

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-ide, xul

With Firefox discontinuing the use XUL overlay it raises concerns that Selenium IDE requires this overlay to function. Can anyone confirm one way or the other?

[Mozilla Will Deprecate XUL Add-ons Before the End of 2017](https://tech.slashdot.org/story/17/02/17/1635216/mozilla-will-deprecate-xul-add-ons-before-the-end-of-2017)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask something like this...

Comment: Asking for an alternative is explicitly off-topic for Stack Overflow: "Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." Given that your question does not require that sub-question, I have edited it out.

Comment: @Makyen apologies and thank you :) I have only been on stakoverflow for about 2 weeks :)

Comment: To close voter(s): This is about a topic that is included as on-topic under ["software tools commonly used by programmers"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Thus, it is on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Selenium IDE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/) is definitely an overlay/XUL based add-on. It contains an *instal.rdf* file and *chrome.manifest* file which uses the `overlay` directive.

[Mozilla has stated](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2017/02/16/the-road-to-firefox-57-compatibility-milestones/) that *all* types of extensions, other than WebExtensions, will be disabled in the near future. [They have stated](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2017/02/16/the-road-to-firefox-57-compatibility-milestones/) that the target for this is the 2017-11-14 release of Firefox 57. This deprecation may include complete themes, which they have stated "we will provide more details on what’s coming for themes very soon". That XUL based extensions would be deprecated was [announced on 2015-08-15](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/08/21/the-future-of-developing-firefox-add-ons/). The fact that they would be disabled in Firefox 57 (late 2017) was [announced on 2016-11-23](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/11/23/add-ons-in-2017/).

Mozilla has previously stated that such add-ons will not be explicitly disabled in [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/) and [Nightly](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/desktop/). However, a primary reason for deprecating such add-ons is that Mozilla wants the freedom to change the underlying Firefox code without worrying about add-on compatibility, other than WebExtensions. Thus, Firefox may change such that the features such add-ons rely upon are no longer available. Another alternative would be to use an [Extended Service Release (ESR) version of Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/faq/). Firefox ESR 52 will be the current ESR at that time. My answer to "[How to develop legacy Firefox add-ons in the future?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42564013/3773011)" has more detail about possible options for continuing to use legacy add-ons.

I have not seen anything from Selenium IDE describing their plans for this change.