# Driver error in Firefox Quantum with Selenium and XUL

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, firefox-quantum

Version:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Mozilla Firefox 58.0
- Selenium-3.7.0

Example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", True)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Error in Firefox with Python-Selenium:

```
XML read error: entity not defined
Location: chrome://browser/content/browser.xul
Line number 1165, column 7:
      <menuitem class="pageActionContextMenuItem extensionUnpinned"
------^
```

Note:
The error also appears if you use FIrefox Quantum in Ubuntu 12.

Comment: Could be an encoding issue. Try that please.

Comment: @OlafSzmidt #!/usr/bin/env python and # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- ??

Comment: IMO, `Firefox Quantum (Released)` version is **`57.0`** Are you using `Mozilla Firefox Quantum v58.0` from **`Nightly`** / **`Beta`** / **`Developers`** ?

Comment: @DebanjanB I am using repository ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315187/is-selenium-ide-an-xul-add-on-in-firefox

Comment: @jbelenus I am experiencing the same issue (while just starting firefox w/o selenium or anything). I created a bugreport here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1420775
Feel free to chime in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation: [Is selenium IDE an XUL add-on in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315187/is-selenium-ide-an-xul-add-on-in-firefox)

Solution, use a old version to 58 of Firefox:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge firefox
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox=57.0+build4-0ubuntu0.16.04.5
```

Thanks to @DebanjanB